# Why do people call Rama's family poor?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

Although Rama's father is the owner of a famous newspaper, the people of the village call them poor. Why?

Comment: They belly full but them hungry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rama's dad went to his local newsagent, and bought a newspaper. He now owns it; but, because he's on the social, he hasn't any more money.

Comment: it could be worse, The newpaper could be their home.

Answer (score 1):

This could be stupid but -

They call him poor because-

> His surname is Poor?

Comment: I saw this kind of mistake also before. They don't call 'him' poor, they call 'them' poor.